# Eclipse - Convert IPath to URL

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I convert an IPath to a URL. In my case, I want to convert the output location of a Java project to a URL, so that I can load classes from there with the `URLClassLoader`. My code looks like this:

```
javaProject.getProject().build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD, null);

URL url = new File( javaProject.getOutputLocation().toFile().getAbsolutePath() ).toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> c = classLoader.loadClass(fully-qualified-class-name);
```

The problem is that the URL is only a relative one, i.e. its string representation is `file:/C:/com.florianingerl.regexfindandreplace.matchevaluators/bin` but it should be something like `file:/C:/Users/Hermann/runtime-EclipseApplication/com.florianingerl.regexfindandreplace.matchevaluators/bin`

The `URLClassLoader` can't find the classes obviously.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```java
IPath path = javaProject.getOutputLocation();

IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);

URI uri = file.getLocationURI();

URL url = uri.toURL();
```